# SPX 500 Monthly Return Google Finance

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I need to formulate the SPX500 return from "x start date" to "x end date".

I have managed to figure out "x start date" to current date (year to date return) but I cant work out how to do historical to fixed date.

Here's what I have thus far for year to date yield.

I need to work out returns from 1/1/21 to 31/1/21 for the S&P500

```
=(googlefinance("INDEXSP:.INX","price")/index(googlefinance("INDEXSP:.INX","price",date(2021,1,1)),2,2)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax for allows you to get the `GOOGLE FINANCE` data for 1 January (using `INDEX()`). Surely, then you use the same syntax for the relevant end date

Try this formula:

`=(index(GoogleFinance($B$1,$B$2,B5),2,2)-index(GoogleFinance($B$1,$B$2,B4),2,2))/index(GoogleFinance($B$1,$B$2,B4),2,2)`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]